# Change fragments order and passing datas android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 fragments 1,2,3,4. I want to switch from 3 to 2, so the new order will be 1,3,2,4.
Everything's ok except I lost my passing datas and no bugs, just a quiet refusal ! lol
Here's a part of the code for fragments :

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageCreator.class.getName())); // 1
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageRecette.class.getName())); // 2
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageArome.class.getName()));   // 3   
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageUser.class.getName()));    // 4

this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

The well known passing datas (from 2 and 3 fragments to Activity) :

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {       
 // Passing Datas to MainActivity
 Click_status = 0;
 mListener.onListItemSelected(item_name, id, Click_status, Fsa.Press_pos);
}
 @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

try {
            mListener = (onListItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement onListItemSelectedListener");
        }
}
```

then in the same fragment :

```
 public interface onListItemSelectedListener{
    public void onListItemSelected(String item_name, int id, int Click_status, int Press_pos);
 }
```

All these datas are passed to the main activity

```
 import com.tutos.PageRecette.onListItemSelectedListener; //Passing Datas
 import com.tutos.PageArome.onLongClickSelectedListener;
```

then the methods etc...

Everythings works good before the fragments switching - datas are passed,
then if I change the order or the fragments, I lost them.

```
  fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageCreator.class.getName())); // 1 
  fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageArome.class.getName()));   // 3  
  fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageRecette.class.getName())); // 2   
  fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageUser.class.getName()));    // 4
```

Any Clues ? Thanks for reading me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this data is shared between two or more fragment then you can add this data to the activity and you can access it inside your fragments any time by using

```
((Your Activity class name)getActivity())."the getter or setter method"
```

You also can make them static if they are shared access multiple activities.

Comment: After checking, it appears it's a graphical problem, datas are there but the settext doesn't work... sorry